# Reset specific slot and ask question again in Rasa NLU

Tags: python, rasa-nlu, rasa

I am building a chatbot for table reservation in a hotel.
I have written a custom action to validate and modify the extracted user input. I want to reset my slot and ask the question again if the flag value is False.
Here's my actions.py file:

```
from typing import Any, Text, Dict, List, Union

from rasa_sdk import Action, Tracker
from rasa_sdk.events import SlotSet, UserUtteranceReverted, EventType, AllSlotsReset
from rasa_sdk.executor import CollectingDispatcher
from word2number import w2n
from .functions import util

class ValidateRestaurantForm(Action):
    def name(self) -> Text:
        return "user_details_form"

    def run(self, dispatcher: CollectingDispatcher, tracker: Tracker, domain: Dict) -> List[EventType]:

        required_slots = ["number_table", "table_type", "reserve_time"]

        for slot_name in required_slots:
            if tracker.slots.get(slot_name) is None:    
                # The slot is not filled yet. Request the user to fill this slot next.
                return [SlotSet("requested_slot", slot_name)]

        # All slots are filled.
        return [SlotSet("requested_slot", None)]

class ActionSubmit(Action):
    def name(self) -> Text:
        return "action_submit"

    def run(
        self,
        dispatcher,
        tracker: Tracker,
        domain: "DomainDict",
    ) -> List[Dict[Text, Any]]:

        number_table = tracker.get_slot("number_table")
        number_table = w2n.word_to_num(number_table)
        table_type = tracker.get_slot("table_type")
        reserve_time = tracker.get_slot("reserve_time")

        flag, reserve_time_modified = util(reserve_time)
                
        if flag == False:
            dispatcher.utter_message(response="utter_deny_reserve_time")
            dispatcher.utter_message(response="utter_ask_reserve_time")
            return [SlotSet("reserve_time", None)] <-------Resetting the slot and ask 
                                                           reservation time again
        
        else:
            dispatcher.utter_message(response="utter_submit",
                                    number_table=number_table,
                                    table_type=tracker.get_slot("table_type"),
                                    reserve_time=reserve_time_modified)
        return [AllSlotsReset()]
```

I am not able to find any answers on Rasa forums. Please suggest some ideas to solve this problem. I am a beginner in Rasa.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like something that can be done by writing [stories that implement branching logic](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/writing-stories/#implementing-branching-logic).

You can make flag a slot and have it's value set by `ActionSubmit`. Then, you can write a story where if after calling `ActionSubmit` and the flag slot is false, you activate the form.

**Update 2021-05-08**

This part of `ActionSubmit`:

`flag, reserve_time_modified = util(reserve_time)`

could be a separate action named e.g. `is_valid_reserve_time` that ends with a call to set the `flag` and `reserve_time_modified` slot.

Then, you could write a story that branches depending the value of the `flag` slot.

Alternatively, you could use a form to collect all the required booking information and validate the value users provide to `reserve_time` as it gets filled. The docs has an example of [validating an input](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/forms/#validating-form-input) that user provides to a form and asking the user to fill again if the input is invalid.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'am getting this flag value from a different function "util" which takes as input the reservation time and checks if the reserve_time is in the range (7pm to 10 pm). If it is in the range then it return True otherwise False.

Comment: @nick I've updated my answer. What are your thoughts on using forms to validate the reserve time?